# Prevent div block from moving when window resized

Tags: css, html, resize

I have a div block that overlays on top of its parent div, but when the window is resized, the child div moves around like crazy. How can I prevent that from happening. Here is the link to my site: http://raider.grcc.edu/~ryanduffing/recordstore/

Here is the relevant CSS code, and HTML code:

```
            <div id="overlayDescription" class="my_corner">
                <span id="overHeader"><span id="chevron">&#187;</span>THE CORNER</span>
                <span id="overHeader2">RECORD SHOP</span>
                <p id="overContent"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="pictureBox">
                <img src="img/storefront.jpg" />
            </div>

#pictureBox{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 940px;
    height: 420px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#overlayDescription{
    font-size: 11px;
     position:absolute;
    top: 290px;
    right: 489px;
    height: 265px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    width: 240px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
}

#overlayDescription span#overHeader{
    font-family: Arial Narrow;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 80px;
    top: 10px;
}

#overlayDescription span#chevron{
    position:relative;
    left: -5px;
    font-family: Arial Narrow;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: yellow;
}

#overlayDescription span#overHeader2{
    font-family: Arial Narrow;
    color: yellow;
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 80px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#overlayDescription p#overContent{
    position:absolute;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the child's absolute position relative to its parent.

```
#content {
    position: relative;
}

#overlayDescription {
    top: 140px;
    right: 327px;
    /* rest of the styles for this element */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you give your child div absolute position means that this element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.

But as I can see from your website, all parent divs of your `#overlayDescription` div are static positioned element since `static` is the default position value.

So currently, your div are positioned according to your `html` element which is your window so you need to give one of its parent another position method rather then static then you'll be fine, for example:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: relative;` on `div.content`.

Then set `right: 0px;` on `#overlayDescription` and adjust the `top` value to get it to sit in the right spot vertically.