# How to position 3 divs in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, position

I have 3 divs. A top, another center and one bottom.
I intend to make the div center div start where top ends and ends where the div bottom start.

The same want the div center does not lose its position when the browser is resized

Someone can help me?

My code:

```
<header>TOP</header>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="divCenter">

            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>BOTTOM</footer>
```

I want make the divCenter resizable with the browser

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly,and if possible show us what have you tried ?

Comment: @AviralSingh i edited the question ... its now clear?

Comment: Still a little confused with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user2647038, Maybe you should have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534123/prevent-div-block-from-moving-when-window-resized).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to what you are trying to achieve would be to apply a css property of position absolute to your middle div like so:

```
#dialog-window {
  position:absolute;
  top:/*some height*/
}
```

This will keep the div in place. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand from your question, you want three divs (top, center, and bottom) stacked on top of each other and you do not want the order of the divs to be changed when the window is resized. Here is some code that could do that:

```css
#top , #center , #bottom{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="top"><h1>Top</h1></div>
      <div id="center"><h1>Center</h1></div>
      <div id="bottom"><h1>Bottom</h1></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code creates three divs (top, center, and bottom) that take up the entire screen. Since they are relative to the screen, they will be resizable. However, they will maintain their positions.